# How do I cycle through a linked list to reduce a value?

Tags: c++, class, function, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have a class called SensorNode, which contains (among other things) a linked list of sensor objects.  The node has a data member for the amount of battery power it has left, and the sensors each have a data member for how much power they draw.  I have a function called processTimeClick that is supposed to go through the entire linked list of sensors in the node, and subtract the amount of power that they use from the battery that the node has left.  Unfortunately I get an "Error, bad access code" and I don't know why.  Here's the function I have, I was hoping someone could see where my logic is wrong.

```
void SensorNode::processTimeClick() {
    if (batt == 0) {

    }
    else {
        temp = mySensors;
        do {
            if (batt <=0) {
                cout << "\nThis node has run out of battery\n";
                func = 0;
                break;
            }
            batt = (batt - (temp->SensEl->getPC()));
            temp = temp->LLelement;

        } while (temp->LLelement != NULL); //My code stops here and says "Thread   1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
        }
    }
```

to make it easier to understand:
temp and mySensors are both pointers (declared in the SensorNode class) of type "SensorBlock" (which is the linked list object). batt is a float data member in the SnesorNode class.

Here's the declaration for the SensorBlock class:

```
class SensorBlock {

    friend class SensorNode;
    SensorBlock * LLelement;
    sensor * SensEl;
    SensorBlock(sensor* senspoint);
};
SensorBlock::SensorBlock(sensor* senspoint) {
    SensEl = senspoint;
    LLelement = NULL;
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You haven't done anything to make sure temp isn't null the first time through.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention that mySensors is initialized to NULL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want your loop to look more like this:

```
    while (temp) {
        if (batt <=0) {
            cout << "\nThis node has run out of battery\n";
            func = 0;
            break;
        }
        batt = (batt - (temp->SensEl->getPC()));
        temp = temp->LLelement;

    }
```

This way, `temp` is checked to make sure it isn't null before you try to use it.

If you have a loop like this:

```
do {
  // use temp
  temp = temp->LLelement;
} while (temp->LLelement);
```

it is equivalent to

```
beginning_of_loop:
  // use temp -- oops it might be null!
  temp = temp->LLelement;
  // temp might be null here
  if (temp->LLelement) goto beginning_of_loop;
```

If you put the while at the top it is equivalent to this:

```
beginning_of_loop:
  if (!temp) goto end_of_loop:
  // use temp -- can't be null
  temp = temp->LLelement;
  // temp might be null here, but we aren't using it
  goto beginning_of_loop;
end_of_loop:
```

Comment: ^ That fixed it!  Would you mind explaining why though?  when will while(temp) stop running?  And why was while (temp->LLelement != NULL) not good? I'm just trying to learn this stuff a bit better.

Comment: `while` will stop when it's no longer `true`, or it hits a `break`. Also you could exit the block with a `return` statement, or by throwing an exception. Also, `goto`, but I won't mention that any further.

Comment: @Acoustic77: I added some explanation.